# Asp.Net Core 2 Authentication/Session not working in chrome 3rd Party Redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Problem is only in chrome browser Using Asp.net core 2.0

First of all this problem is only in Chrome browser. I have integrated 3rd part payment module after coming back from payment website my application is losing all the information related to user and redirecting it to login page and its only in chrome.

Not authorizing user and I am using asp.net core Identity.

Can you please help me out? Much thanks and appreciated.

Comment: Looks like that after the redirect the browser is not sending the authentication cookies back. Are the cookies constrained to a path or domain?

Comment: Yes, Cookies have the domain and after redirection I can still see them in the browser.

Comment: Read about SameSite, a new standard in chrome and Core2 dealing with cookies and redirects. Are any of your missing cookies marked with this?